# php: time limit exceeded `Success' @ fatal/cache.c/GetImagePixelCache/2042

Tags: php, json, wordpress, import

I'm import data from a CRM Server by JSON to Wordpress.

I know that the load may take several minutes, so the script runs outside Wordpress. And I execute "php load_data.php"

But when the script reaches the part where we upload the images, it throws an error:

**php: time limit exceeded `Success' @ fatal/cache.c/GetImagePixelCache/2042.**

and it stops.

This is my code to upload image to media:

```
<?php
function upload_image_to_media($postid, $image_url, $set_featured=0) {

    $tmp = download_url( $image_url );

    // fix filename for query strings
    preg_match( '/[^\?]+\.(jpg|jpe|jpeg|gif|png)/i', $image_url, $matches );

    $before_name = $postid == 0 ? 'upload' : $postid;
    $file_array = array(
        'name'     => $before_name . '_' . basename( $matches[0] ),
        'tmp_name' => $tmp
    );

    // Check for download errors
    if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
        @unlink( $file_array['tmp_name'] );
        return false;
    }

    $media_id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $postid );

    // Check for handle sideload errors.
    if ( is_wp_error( $media_id ) ) {
        @unlink( $file_array['tmp_name'] );
        return false;
    }

    if( $postid != 0 && $set_featured == 1 )
        set_post_thumbnail( $postid, $media_id );

    return $media_id;
}
?>
```

They are like 50 posts and each one has 10 large images.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The default execution time is 30 seconds so looks you are exceeding that. We have a similar script that downloads up to a couple thousand photos per run. Adding set_time_limit(60) to reset timer each loop fixed timeout issues. In your case you can probably just add at the beginning of the function. Just be very careful you don't get any infinite loops as they will run forever (or until the next reboot).

Comment: I put set_time_limit(0)  and the result was the same error.

Comment: I put set_time_limit(60) in the function and the result was the same error

Answer (score 0):

To make sure it works you can add the below as the first line inside your upload function

```
set_time_limit(0)
```

this will allow it to run until it's finished, but watch it as this will let it run forever which WILL hurt your servers available memory. But to see if the script works put that in there, then adjust to proper time if need be.

If you get another or the same error it will at least verify its not a time issue (error messages are not always factual).

The other possibility is that you are on a shared server and are exceeding their time allotment for you server. (continuous processor use for more then 30 seconds, as an example).

Comment: I put set_time_limit(0)  and the result was the same error. Yes it is a shared hosting.

Comment: then you are probably hitting the limit of your shared hosting usage policy, contact them and they will check the logs and see.